# How to group by a value in xslt

Tags: xml, group-by, xslt-2.0

I am having an xml with item values

```
<value1>
        <OrderLine OrderedQty="1.00" Type="cancel" >
            <Item ItemID="1234">                
            </Item>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine OrderedQty="1.00" Type="cancel" >
            <Item ItemID="1234">
            </Item>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine OrderedQty="1.00" Type="blabla" >
            <Item ItemID="1234">
            </Item>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine OrderedQty="1.00" Type="asdsd" >
            <Item ItemID="4567">
            </Item>
        </OrderLine>
</value1>
```

I want to get the item id's which are not canceled but some of them are canceled.The item 4567 nothing is done to it so we wont update it.

```
<item>
<id>1234</id>
<quantity>1</quantity>
</item>
```

XSLT:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xp20="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.Xpath20">
    <tns:Root-Element>    
      <xsl:for-each-group select="/value1/OrderLine" group-by="Item/@ItemID">

      </xsl:for-each-group>
</tns:Root-Element>
```

I dont have much xsl code.I need to update the orders which are not canceled.If you take itemid 4567 there is no change so we dont want anything form it.

Comment: Can you add the XSLT that you've tried and explain where you are having issues?

Comment: @DanielHaley i have updated the code .I dont have much xsl code .This is just the part of code i need so i have updated according.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started...

**XML Input** (additional `OrderLine` added for testing)

```
<value1>
    <OrderLine OrderedQty="1.00" Type="cancel" >
        <Item ItemID="1234">                
        </Item>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine OrderedQty="1.00" Type="cancel" >
        <Item ItemID="1234">
        </Item>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine OrderedQty="1.00" Type="blabla" >
        <Item ItemID="1234">
        </Item>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine OrderedQty="1.00" Type="asdsd" >
        <Item ItemID="4567">
        </Item>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine OrderedQty="2.00" Type="qwerty" >
        <!--ADDED ITEM FOR TESTING-->
        <Item ItemID="1234"/>
    </OrderLine>
</value1>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <root>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="OrderLine[not(@Type='cancel')]/Item" group-by="@ItemID">
        <xsl:if test="count(current-group()) > 1">
          <item>
            <id><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></id>
            <quantity>
              <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/../@OrderedQty)"/>
            </quantity>
          </item>          
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<root>
   <item>
      <id>1234</id>
      <quantity>3</quantity>
   </item>
</root>
```

Notes:

- You didn't have the prefix `tns` bound to a namespace, so I just used a generic element (`root`) for the root element.
- I assumed when you said `The item 4567 nothing is done to it so we wont update it.` you meant that since it wasn't added to another item, we drop the element (since it's not in your output example).
- `OrderLine/@Type` is ignored other than checking for the value of "cancel".

Comment: I will try this out and let you knwo but
In the output we should get quantity as 1 ?
As we are selecting the items which are of not the type cancel and will it work if we have
<OrderLine OrderedQty="1.00" Type="cancel" >
        <Item ItemID="8900">
        </Item>
    </OrderLine>
In the output will it show
<root>
   <item>
      <id>1234</id>
      <quantity>3</quantity>
   </item>
<item>
      <id>8900</id>
      <quantity>0</quantity>
   </item>

</root>

Comment: @NikhilPreeth - If you use your original input, you'll get the quantity of `1`. I added an additional `OrderLine` for testing (noted in the answer).

Comment: @NikhilPreeth - Were you able to try this out?